# Gradle dependency and space in path

Tags: groovy, javafx-2, gradle

i am creating a Gradle plugin

when i try to set a jar path to project.dependencies compile which is having space, i am getting  exception

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'visage-gradle-sample'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection) values: [file collection]
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
```

I am trying to set it in MyPlugin apply method

```
    private void configureSetup(project) {


    final javafxHome = System.env["JAVAFX_HOME"]

    def jfxJar =''

    if (javafxHome) {
        jfxJar = "${javafxHome}${File.separator}rt${File.separator}lib${File.separator}jfxrt.jar"
    }
    else{
        final javaHome = System.env["JAVA_HOME"]
        jfxJar = "${javaHome}${File.separator}jre${File.separator}lib${File.separator}jfxrt.jar"
    }

    if(!(new File(jfxJar)).exists())
    throw new StopExecutionException("JAVAFX_HOME is not set or your JDK is not having JAVAFX jar.")

        project.dependencies  {
          compile project.files(jfxJar)
    }

}
```

I am trying to set JavaFX 2 jfxrt.jar which is in following path

```
 C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar
```

the debug shows

```
 15:36:31.036 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection) values: [file collection]
 Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
 15:36:31.051 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.methodMissing(DefaultDependencyHandler.groovy:94)
 15:36:31.067 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.invokeMethod(DefaultDependencyHandler.groovy)
 15:36:31.082 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.visage.gradle.plugin.VisagePlugin$_configureSetup_closure1.doCall(VisagePlugin.groovy:122)
 15:36:31.098 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:141)
 15:36:31.114 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:90)
 15:36:31.129 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.dependencies(AbstractProject.java:879)
 15:36:31.129 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.Project$dependencies.call(Unknown Source)
 15:36:31.160 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.visage.gradle.plugin.VisagePlugin.configureSetup(VisagePlugin.groovy:121)
 15:36:31.176 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.visage.gradle.plugin.VisagePlugin.this$2$configureSetup(VisagePlugin.groovy)
 15:36:31.176 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.visage.gradle.plugin.VisagePlugin$this$2$configureSetup.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 15:36:31.207 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.visage.gradle.plugin.VisagePlugin.apply(VisagePlugin.groovy:67)
 15:36:31.207 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.visage.gradle.plugin.VisagePlugin.apply(VisagePlugin.groovy)
 15:36:31.223 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:107)
 15:36:31.239 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:71)
 15:36:31.254 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:37)
 15:36:31.270 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
 15:36:31.285 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
 15:36:31.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
 15:36:31.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
 15:36:31.348 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:840)
 15:36:31.364 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
 15:36:31.379 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
 15:36:31.395 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 15:36:31.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at build_1c4c4h5n90lk41hinuth6in4rk.run(D:\MyWorkBench\jugchennai\visage-gradle-plugin\visage-gradle-sample\build.gradle:8)
 15:36:31.410 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
 15:36:31.426 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 29 more
 15:36:31.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
 15:36:31.457 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
```

How to over come space in path ?

Comment: Can you expand the stacktrace a little bit (to see what method signature is Groovy trying to match?), or add to the question how do you wrote the dependency line. 
There is no problem with spaces in Gradle (in the end it uses Java file API). For the information that you gave, probably you have to use / (instead of \) or escape the \ with \\

Comment: @Raj can you post where you're trying to set this property?

Comment: @tim_yates i added the code and place.

Comment: This isn't to do with it having a space.  Is this a subproject?  Can you post slightly more of your gradle file?  3 lines of it isn't enough I don't think...  ie:  what is `jfxJar`?

Comment: @tim_yates sorry now it will be clear i hope :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like the problem is related to a space in a path. I assume the code doesn't apply the `java` plugin, hence there is no `compile` configuration.

By the way, it is never necessary to use `File.separator` when passing paths to Gradle. Just use `/` and Gradle will do the right thing.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. I was using a custom dependency resolver, and didn't notice that I was adding the custom dependency _before_ applying the java plugin. I spent a day hunting through the gradle source code before I noticed this!